# How to list all the IAM roles that include a given permission in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam

After discovering that a user (principal) needs an additional permission to perform a task, I would like to know what standard roles include that permission so I can add the role to the user. I would also like to know what other permissions each of those roles provide so I can select the one with permissions that match the user's needs. I am not able to use custom roles, and I am avoiding the basic roles as they are too wide.

At present, I am using https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#support-roles.
I search for the permission, then scroll up to the see the role name and all the other permissions in that role.

It works but is slow for what must be a common task.

Is there a better web page or a gcloud api command that would work better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The GCP documentation offers [a (huge) page](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) that allows you to identify the different roles that grant them.

In addition to the page you cited you can later, using the `gcloud` CLI, [describe a role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles?hl=en#getting_the_role_metadata) and see the different permissions it grants. For example:

```
gcloud iam roles describe roles/iam.roleViewer
```

The command will output:

```
description: Read access to all custom roles in the project.
etag: AA==
includedPermissions:
- iam.roles.get
- iam.roles.list
- resourcemanager.projects.get
- resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy
name: roles/iam.roleViewer
stage: GA
title: Role Viewer
```

AFAIK, the `gcloud` CLI doesn't give you the opportunity to, given a certain permission, get the roles that grant it.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/choose-predefined-roles#find-roles) one can [check the pre-defined roles given a permission](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference)

Comment: Thanks for the first link, it gives an overview or roles. The second link is the same as the first answer. It links to a page showing the roles associated with any permission. Which is perfect.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the second link was already in the previous answer, I missed that ;-)